# Assign value with optional question mark

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently learning Swift from basics. Now I'm on optionals and I'm trying to understand this case:

```
var text: String? = nil

text? = "some text"
```

What happens exactly if we assign value with question mark? I don't understand why the value of text is `nil`. Can you explain me what is the difference between assigning `text = "some text"` and `text? = "some text"`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right to be surprised. `text? =` means "If `text` is `nil` don't perform the assignment."

You've stumbled across a highly obscure language feature. See https://ericasadun.com/2017/01/25/pretty-much-every-way-to-assign-optionals/
(As she rightly says, you can count on the fingers of zero hands the number of times you'll ever actually talk like this, because who would ever want to assign a value only just in case the lvalue is already non-nil?)

**NOTE** I prefer to look at this as a zero-length variant of optional chaining. It is extremely useful to be able to say e.g.

```
self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true
```

meaning, if `self.navigationController` is `nil`, fuhgeddaboudit. Well, your use case is sort of a variant of that, with nothing after the question mark. Most people are unaware that if the last object in the chain is an Optional, the chain can end in a question mark. The expressions in `f` are all legal:

```
class C {
    struct T {
        var text : String?
    }
    var t : T?
    func f() {
        self.t?.text = "howdy"
        self.t? = T()
        self.t?.text? = "howdy"
    }
}
```

But only the first one, `self.t?.text =`, is common to say in real life.