# Why will UITableViewController navigationItem.searchController not set in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uisearchcontroller, uinavigationitem

For some reason, when I set UITableViewController navigationItem.searchController with a UISearchController, it doesn't take it.

Here is my code:

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    print("?", navigationItem.searchController)
    print("!", searchController)
    navigationItem.searchController? = searchController
    print("?", navigationItem.searchController)
} else {
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
}
```

Here is the debug window:

```
? nil
! <UISearchController: 0x105077600>
? nil
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with search controllers or navigation items. It has to do with the Swift language. You've slammed accidentally into a [little-known edge case in optional chain syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66538951/341994). The problem is this line:

```
navigationItem.searchController? = searchController
```

I don't know what you think that means, but it doesn't mean that! Delete the question mark:

```
navigationItem.searchController = searchController
```